# How to get e-mail from Drupal.org about new Drupal releases?

Tags: 7, updating

I have creates a account in drupal.org website. I saw this https://www.drupal.org/news link to know news about drupal.

Is there a way by which I can get latest updates in my mail without visiting the drupal site

Comment: Enable notification under you profile..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to https://www.drupal.org/user , click on the "Edit" tab and from there, the "My newsletters" tab. This will allow you to subscribe to "Drupal newsletter" and "Security announcements".

Also to get notifications of Drupal core or module updates for a particular Drupal site that you run, go to Reports -> Available updates -> settings (/admin/reports/updates/settings) and enter your email address and the desired frequency (daily / weekly) and type (security / all) of updates.